# is there a pictogram for 'default' or 'leave like it is' - like there is for save (disc) or print (printer)?

Tags: icon

I am working on somthing like interactive CSS editor. For many things in CSS - rules you can find icons/pictograms, like a *I*  for italic text or like this **B** for bold, there are many other examples, I think we all know, or just look at the editor here.

But is there a - lets call it standard - icon / pictogram for "leave it like it is"?

Think about the following:
[image]
[image]
we all have seen this (or a like) normal vs bold, but how should the icon look like for: "dont change", if you want take back "bold" not to override the parent font, that prob is "bold" or "normal"

The question is, are there such pictograms? I dont ask for ideas how the should look like (although as comment I like suggestions)

The point is, that I cant belive, that I am the first one, that needs a 'put back to default' icon/pictogram

**edit**: I am not searching for just "bold or not bold", I think of an icon, thet fits also for "font: Arial / font: inherit" or "border: blue / border: inherit"

Answer (score 2):

I some time ago prepared an icon for my word documents. Was s simple X (cross, not a letter x) That means to me "Remove aditional styles, leave the default one"

Comment: This is also a very good recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are resetting options back to inherit, or resetting these options to their default values I would find an arrow would be appropriate.

By arrow I mean something like [these undo icons](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=undo), here is an example from that page:

[image]

I think that action is very clear and has established meaning.

Alternatively, if you're looking for something that more closely means "inherit" I would still recommend an arrow, but perhaps one that is pointing down in order to try to establish that you are getting something from somewhere else (inheriting the information).

I don't believe there's actually an icon that mean's "default" as it is very situational, but no you are not the first to have this problem, I'm sure.

Comment: I wait a bit with 'accepting', but your suggestion with the undo icons gave me already a big step - its the "crossed edit pencil"

Comment: That's fine. Glad to hear I could help out.